# preg_match for matching any li with different classes

Tags: php, preg-match

Im trying to fetch all the li's of an ordered list but I can't define the pattern, I'm using the regex reference but I don't know how to exactly apply it

```
preg_match('/<li (.*)>(.*)<\/li>/i', $html, $ol);
```

Comment: use DOM http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php There is a famous post on here regarding why

Comment: I've tried with getElementsByTagName but it gives many li's from the website, and I don't know how to apply a filter for only fetching the ol that I want.

Comment: Target the parent element. Perhaps it has a class or id? Or perhaps it is always the `x` `ol` in the page? Without seeing the actual html you are working with, its impossible to help further

Comment: I'm trying to get the parent element but I don't know how to do it. Yes it have  a fixed class but a dynamic id.
I need to get the result ol in: 
https://es.search.yahoo.com/search?p=madrid&fr=yfp-t-777